# Variables are static without being declared so, OSX iOS Apple flavor of C or Obj-C?

Tags: objective-c, ios, c, macos

I came across some, at least to me weird behavior of routines used by Apple in the mouse handling event, in the documentation they use a variable in a static fashion while not declare it so, this was sometime ago, however if you take the GLKit-lib, they kind of show the same behavior, for example something similar to this:

```
GLKVector3 GLKVector3Set(float x, float y, float z)
{
    GLKVector3 v = { x, y, z };
    return v;
}
```

Under normal circumstances all variables declared within a function are placed on the stack and disappears as the function returns the call...

The situation with the mouse-input was something similar to this:

```
(void) mouseInput:(mouseEvent *)event
{
   BOOL hasClicked = NO;
   //
    if(hasClicked)
    {
        //
    } else {
      hasClicked = YES;
    }
}
```

Which would only make sense if the BOOL were declared static...

If anyone knows what I'm talking about and can explain this behavior or refer to Apple's explanation on their site, I'd be happy.

Niels

Comment: There is nothing wrong with returning a local variable *by value* - the problems start when you try to return a reference or pointer to a local variable.

Comment: Thanks Paul, that part is clear. I normally don't pass whole structs that way, so some enlightening has happened today :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first code example is ok. `GLKVector3` is a structure  (really a union), it's not static, it's returned by value. It works exactly as if it was an `int`.

The second code example does not make sense as written (the `if` is removed by the optimizer and will likely give you a warning). But you say *was something similar to*, so I think that you got it wrong. It was not similar to what you posted, it's just you that missed something and understood it as being like that. Post the actual code if you want an explanation of it.

Addendum

As you wrote in the comment how to find the original code, I went and checked. The original code is quite different from your second example. It's something like this:

```
BOOL keepOn = YES;
...
while (keepOn) {
  ....
  switch (...) {
    case ...
      ...
    case ...
      ...
      keepOn = NO;
      break;
    default:
      ...
  }
}
...
```

This does make sense and nothing gets removed by the optimizer. The variable is not static.

Comment: "The second code example does not make sense as written", I guess you didn't notice the question ;) However the following is actual code from Apple's docs:

Comment: Search Apple Docs - Cocoa Event Handling Guide >> Handling Mouse Events >> Listing 4-5

Comment: I did, and I was right. The sample code from Apple is quite different from your sample code. You use an `if`, Apple uses a `while` and there's code in the while that may modify the `hasClicked` flag. Those variables are **not** static at all. And do not behave as static variables.